# TFS2012 Build Process using wrong Workspace Owner

Tags: visual-studio-2012, workspace

I am trying to run a build using Visual Studio 2012 paired with Team Foundation Server 2012. The build process is run on a separate server from the team server. When I run a build definition the build fails and the error message reads:

Exception Message: TF14061: The workspace ENTERPRISE1 - workspace1;ENTERPRISE1$ does not exist. (type WorkspaceNotFoundException)

I agree with the error that this workspace does not exist, the workspace I am looking for is ENTERPRISE1 - workspace1, owned by ts_build, however the build process is somewhere along the way specifying ENTERPRISE1$ as the proposed owner of the workspace. I have made some modifications to the build template, however I am in no way specifying the owner of the workspace. I've never had to specify the workspace owner before in TFS2012...

So.

What the heck is going on? Where/why is this workspace owner being set? How can I fix this?

All help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the TFS Sidekicks from Attrice to look at the workspaces on the build server. If you need to create a workspace with ENTERPRISE1$ as the owner.

Comment: I have access to the build server and its workspaces using a remote desktop connection, through which I have set up my build server workspace with owner ts_build. When I change this owner to ENTERPRISE1$ the build succeeds, however we need the owner to be ts_build. How can I change the owner that the build is looking for from ENTERPRISE1$ to ts_build? Or for that matter, can I completely get rid of the build presuming an owner?

Comment: You should be able to mapped workspace via the TFS Sidekicks, then kick off a build and see the new workspace be created with the correct owner. I assume your build service is running as ts_build, can you help me understand the necessity to change the owner of the workspace?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!

The problem was found on the Team Foundation Server Administration Console on the build machine. On the build configuration tab, at the top of the page it reads

*Build Service configured for [project collection] as [username]*

This was set to NW SERVICES or some baloney. Changed this to the same as the owner of the workspace (ts_build) and everything is kosher.

Lotta headache for a 15 second fix...